# Manual fold issue on both Mac & Ubuntu

Tags: folding, macvim, linux-ubuntu

When I `set foldmethod=manual` and then I'm typing `<zc>`

> E490: No fold found

is raising.

Same story with `set foldmethod=marker`.

The behavior is the same on Mac Sierra and Ubuntu 16.04. I installed vim 8.0.606 instead 7.4.xxx but it doesn't help. Also I compiled 8.0 manually and expected to find a compilation option related to folding but a docs don't refer folding options.

**How to fix it?**

Comment: Um... do you actually *have* any folds in the file where you are running the `zc` command? `zc` closes an existing fold, which, in `manual` and `marker` requires you to have already added folds, either by using commands such as the `zf` operator or, for `marker` by adding the fold markers in yourself.